# Replace all instances of '_' with space. If there more than 1 instance in sequance replace with only 1 space

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to write a Python function, which will replace all instance of underscore with spaces. If there 2 or more consecutive underscores, they need to be replaced by a single space.

I can replace character, but not limit the number of spaces being replaced.

```
def replace_trash(strg):
    newStr = ''
    for i in strg:
        if i != '_':
            newStr += i
        else:
            newStr += ' '
    return newStr

print (replace_trash('Please__help___me_to_solve___this_____problem'))
```

Expected results would be:
Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def replace_trash(strg):
    newStr = ''
    previous = 0
    for i in strg:
        if i != '_':
            newStr += i
            previous = 0
        else:
            if not previous:
                newStr += ' '
            previous = 1
    return newStr
```

Comment: Can you please explain me , how that works. I don't understand how "if not previous" working here

Comment: When à _is found, previous is set to 1. When an other character is fond,  previous is set to 0. Now when a _ is found a space is added ONLY if the previous character  was NOT à _. This is the reason for the "if not previous" condition.

Answer (score 2):

Replace all matches of the regex (*+ = one or more '*')  with a single space

```py
import re
def replace_trash(string):
  return re.sub('_+', ' ', string)


print(replace_trash('Please__help___me_to_solve___this_____problem'))
```